# SQL query to identify records using partition range

Tags: sql, partition

I have below query which is giving only for one partition that 17th October data. But I have to extract information between 17th Oct to 15th Nov. How can we achieve this. Your help is really appreciated.

```
SELECT
 /*+ parallel(c,10)*/
 error_code,
 cdr_source_id,
 FROM error_event partition(day_20171017) c
 WHERE error_code ='220'
 ORDER BY error_date_time;
```

Comment: Do you need data between the 15th and the 17th? Why you don't use in the where condition date between 20171015 and 20171017? Which data format you have? What exactly do you need to get out as results?

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to get the details between specified dates using between will be useful to get the details more easily